# How to find disk usage of files/directories with spaces

Tags: linux, filesystems, filenames, disk-usage

I know I can get disk usage of the files/directories in a directory like this:

```
for file in $(ls); do du --hum --sum $file; done
```

That seems to break down if the files/directories have spaces in their names. So I tried this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | xargs -0 du --hum --sum
```

That yields only this:

```
2.3G    .
```

Whereas there are 8 subdirectories in my directory.

Comment: see: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs, https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting and [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Comment: Also, is there something wrong with just `du -h -s ./*`? Anyway, that `find` fails because it includes `.` in the output, and `du` is smart enough to notice all the other directories are under it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can also just apply the max-depth directive and take out `--sum` in your du invocation like so:**

```
du --hum --max-depth=1
```

It will also display directories with spaces.

Here's example output demonstrating that directories with spaces will show up:

```
4.0K    ./regular_dir1
4.0K    ./regular_dir2
4.0K    ./dir with spaces
```

Answer (score 0):

Not as good as EWJ00:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file; do du --hum --sum "$file"; done
```